# how can I downcast proper class from vector?

Tags: c++, vector

Dog is base object

```
class dog {
    void bark(); (print : I am dog)
}
```

and a lot of child class from dog

```
class Puppy : Dog {
    void bark(); (print : I am a purry)
}

class Puddle : Dog {
    void bark(); (print : I am a puddle)
}
```

put many kinds of child class into "Vector dogs"

```
Vector<Dog *> dogs;

dogs.pushBack(puppy);
dogs.pushBack(puddle);
dogs.pushBack(martiz);
dogs.pushBack(yok);

for (auto dog : dogs) {
    dog->bark();
}
```

all class print "I am a dog"

I want to downcast automatically their origin class.

what is the best way for my case?

Comment: What you want is not a downcast but `virtual void bark()` in `Dog`.

Comment: Better post some realistic, compilable code.

Comment: Note that you use private inheritance. You probably want to declare the derived classes as e.g. `class Puppy : public Dog`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class dog {
   virtual void bark(); (print : I am dog)
}
```

you should set the bark to a virtual void bark and it should work